# Book where 4 major characters where names after the cardinal directions

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

This is a short YA book. It is somewhat a mystery. 4 of the major characters (excluding the POV character) all have last names referencing the cardinal directions.

I would consider the below line a major spoiler for the plot, and a dead giveaway for the book.

> They are all the same person in disguise.

Comment: So...do you know the answer already?

Comment: That's [The Westing Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Westing_Game), but it isn't SF of Fantasy at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *The Westing Game*, by Ellen Raskin, published in 1978 and winner of the Newberry Medal.  I don't think it really qualifies as fantasy or science fiction though (unless you count unrealistic bomb making as SF).

Per Wikipedia:

> Sunset Towers is a new apartment building on Lake Michigan, north of Milwaukee and just down the shore from the mansion owned by reclusive self-made millionaire Samuel W. Westing. (Despite the name, Sunset Towers faces east – into the sunrise.)
>
> As the story opens, a man named Barney Northrup is selling apartments to a carefully selected group of tenants. It soon emerges that most of the tenants – regardless of age or occupation – are named as heirs in Westing's will. The will is structured as a puzzle, with the 16 heirs challenged to find the solution. Each of the eight pairs, assigned seemingly at random, is given $10,000 cash and a different set of baffling clues. The pair that solves the mystery will inherit Westing's entire $200 million fortune and control of his company.

Westing, Northrup, McSouthers, and Eastman all turn out to be the same (not dead) industrialist.